# Radix sort implementation in R

Tags: r, sorting, vector, radix-sort

How do you implement [Radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) in base R (e.g.) for the following vector:

```
vec <- c(25, 478, 34, 9021, 6, 9947, 504, 22)
```

In summary, Radix sort does the following:

- Sort based on `unit` positions:
  `9021   22   34  504   25    6 9947  478`
- Sort based on `ten` positions:
  `504    6 9021   22   25   34 9947  478`
- Sort based on `hundred` positions:
  `6 9021   22   25   34  478  504 9947`
- Sort based on `thousand` positions:
  `6   22   25   34  478  504 9021 9947`

and so on. Of course, `vec` is just an example and the solution is able to deal with data of any length containing numbers of any length.

The output would be `vec` sorted ascending (or descending). That is,

```
6   22   25   34  478  504 9021 9947
```

Comment: Unless you're, specifically, looking to implement radix sort in R, radix sorting is incorporated (from "data.table") in R 3.3.0 -- `sort(vec, method = "radix")`

Comment: @alexis_laz yes, I was in particular curious about implementing the algorithm. Its principle is algorithmically beautiful.

Comment: As a simple, more counting sort style, see `rep(seq_len(max(vec)), tabulate(vec))` (which, with large integers, it will need a large amount of memory) too, which, basically just puts the integers into buckets and selects the non-zero elements

Comment: @alexis_laz a nice one too but it fails for zeros.

Comment: You're right, yes. With the zeros you could use a cheap trick like +/- 1 (`rep(seq_len(max(vec) + 1), tabulate(vec + 1)) - 1`), though there could be more flaws (apart from memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my own solution:

```
f_radixSort <- function(x){
    mx <- nchar(max(x))
    for (i in 1:mx)
        x <- x[order(x%%(10^i))]
    return(x)
}
```

And sample call along with a print of step by step sorting.

```
f_radixSort(vec)

# units
# [1] 9021   22   34  504   25    6 9947  478

# tens
# [1]  504    6 9021   22   25   34 9947  478

# hundreds
# [1]    6 9021   22   25   34  478  504 9947

# thousands
# [1]    6   22   25   34  478  504 9021 9947

# ten thousands
# [1]    6   22   25   34  478  504 9021 9947
```

And a short **BENCHMARKING** (I did not include the sorting using `data.table` as I do not know what is whose principle and, moreover, I asked about an answer in base R):

```
library(microbenchmark)
vec <- c(25, 478, 34, 9021, 6, 9947, 504, 22)

all(radix(vec)==f_radixSort(vec))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(radix(vec), f_radixSort(vec))

# Unit: microseconds
             # expr     min      lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
       # radix(vec) 857.239 915.230 980.39907 943.4745 1005.071 2081.051   100
 # f_radixSort(vec)  39.061  42.216  52.28206  51.0810   54.686  111.775   100

# ========================================================
set.seed(200)
vec<-sample(10000,5000)

all(radix(vec)==f_radixSort(vec))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(radix(vec), f_radixSort(vec))

# Unit: milliseconds
             # expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
       # radix(vec) 6.724506 7.003191 8.135387 7.877256 8.195904 52.786763   100
 # f_radixSort(vec) 2.132132 2.167436 2.302167 2.200337 2.268544  4.009464   100
```

Comment: Very nice solution, but when you call `order` does that still count as a true radix sort? It is my understanding that radix does not sort as per traditional methods. It breaks each digit into 'buckets', retaining their original order within those buckets, then combines the buckets in the correct order. Thus my implementation with the loop of `a<-... b<-...`

Comment: Actually, I suppose it does work. `order` doesn't sort anything. Just gives the order...

Comment: However, you could get the same results by just skipping to the final iteration of the loop: `all(vec[order(vec%%10^nchar(max(vec)))] == f_radixSort(vec))`

Comment: @BryanGoggin even `vec[order(vec)]` would simply give the sorted numbers but it does not obey the algorithm's principle.

Answer (score 1):

I know that `data.table` implements radix sort out of the box, so you could use that package and, for example, sort your data by simply setting the key:

```
library(data.table)

vec <- c(25, 478, 34, 9021, 6, 9947, 504, 22)

f1<-function(vec){
  DT<-data.table(vec)
setkey(DT, vec)
DT
}

f1(vec)

    vec
1:    6
2:   22
3:   25
4:   34
5:  478
6:  504
7: 9021
8: 9947
```

I suppose you *could* implement the algorithm yourself, but It would likely be slow in R. The function would look something like this:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

radix<-function(numbers){
  digits<-nchar(max(numbers))
  numbers<-str_pad(numbers, digits, pad = "0")
  rad<-data.frame(matrix(0, ncol = digits, nrow = length(numbers)))

  for(i in 1:digits){
    rad[,i] <- str_sub(numbers, i,i)
  }

  for(z in rev(1:ncol(rad))){
    a <- which(rad[,z] ==  0 )
    b <- which(rad[,z] ==  1 )
    c <- which(rad[,z] ==  2 ) 
    d <- which(rad[,z] ==  3 )
    e <- which(rad[,z] ==  4 ) 
    f <- which(rad[,z] ==  5 )
    g <- which(rad[,z] ==  6 ) 
    h <- which(rad[,z] ==  7 )
    i <- which(rad[,z] ==  8 ) 
    j <- which(rad[,z] ==  9 )

    k<-c(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j)
    rad<-rad[k,]
  }

  rad<-rad %>% unite_(col = "num", from = colnames(rad), sep = "")
  return(as.numeric(rad$num))
}
```

It could be cleaned/speed up, but this does the radix sort, as I understand it:

```
radix(vec)
[1]    6   22   25   34  478  504 9021 9947
```

To compare speed:

```
microbenchmark(f1(vec), radix(vec))

Unit: microseconds
      expr    min     lq mean median     uq     max neval
   f1(vec)  290.6  314.8  335    327  349.1   524.1   100
radix(vec) 1062.8 1121.7 1458   1163 1250.5 24407.9   100
```

Larger speed comparison:

```
set.seed(200)
more<-sample(10000,5000)
microbenchmark(f1(more), radix(more))

       expr     min      lq  mean  median      uq     max neval
   f1(more)   539.3   565.5   623   622.2   664.8   769.7   100
radix(more) 10457.8 10668.0 11683 11133.7 12298.3 25010.6   100
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I voted up anyway. But do both `f1` and your `radix` function follow the principle of radix sort to sort the data? Would it be possible to print each step of sorting for the purpose of verfication?

Comment: I believe that function does a radix sort by least significant digit i.e. starting with the 1s digit, then 10s, etc. You could add a call to print at the end of each loop to watch it work. It will sort right to left.

Comment: You do not need the first `for` loop in your function as you can convert `numbers` to a data frame or matrix in a vectorized way.

Comment: Putting the speed of your algorithm aside, the space it needs is also considerable which is a matrix where `nrow=length of vec` and `ncol=length of maximum number in vec`

Answer (score 0):

My solution look slike this - please bear with me, I am a beginner ;-)
But the results are correct:

```
radixSort <- function(sortvec) {
  mx <- nchar(max(sortvec))
  ## for all digits up to the number of digits in the longest number:  
  for (i in 1:mx){
    ## empty the 10 buckets
    bucket <- list()
    ## for all 10 buckets:
    for (bucketnumber in 1:10){
      ## fill each bucket with the appropriate numbers
      bucket[[bucketnumber]] <- sortvec[dig(sortvec, i)==(bucketnumber-1)]
    }
    ## empty the sorted vector
    sortvec <- c()
    ## fill the sorted vector with the the contents of buckets 1-10
    for (k in 1:10){
      sortvec <- c(sortvec, bucket[[k]])
    }
  }
  return(sortvec)
}

dig <- function(x, st) {
  ## returns the value of digit #st in number x, e.g. dig(3456, 2) returns 5
  remainder <- x%%(10^st)
  divisor <- 10^(st-1)
  return(trunc(remainder/divisor))
}
```